# Selenium FireFox Proxy Issue

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have googled this issue quite a lot today and i cannot seem to come up with a solution, my code looks ok but when i select a random proxy from a listBox it doesn't seem to be getting used.

**Code:**

```
                if (chkBoxProxies.Checked == true)
                {
                    // Random proxy.
                    Random random = new Random();
                    int c = listBoxMain.Items.Count;
                    int r = random.Next(c);
                    string s = listBoxMain.Items[r].ToString();
                    string[] spl = s.Split(':');
                    // Random proxy.

                    //Helpers.ReturnMessage(spl[0] + " > " + spl[1]);
                    _firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
                    _firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http", spl[0]);
                    _firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http_port", spl[1]);
                }
```

I just split the proxy using the **:** as the seperator, it all looks fine, but during testing by loading the site: https://www.ipinfo.io/ it still shows my real ip address, any help would be appreciated.